# What is the best way to add a LED indicator to an open-drain sensor that's read with a GPIO?

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, gpio, proximity-sensor

I'm designing a circuit around a QRD1113 optical proximity sensor. Its output is open-drain, and I'm implementing a 10k pullup.

The signal is ultimately read by a GPIO on a RPI.

I'd like to add a small LED that turns on when the sensor activates, but I'm unsure of the best way to do it without causing issues with the GPIO. My instinct is to put the LED as if I were driving it directly with the sensor, and connecting the GPIO and pullup to the cathode as normal.

My design is below - is this a sound approach?

[image: Proposed Design]

Comment: What you have shown should work perfectly.  The main thing to note is that the LED voltage supply is the same as the micro.

Comment: Is it important that the sensor is activated or that the RPi recognizes the signal?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm assuming you mean the LED is activated - and I care more about the RPI getting the signal.

Comment: @DwayneReid - By "note" do you mean that that's important for it to work (ie, I shouldn't change the LED supply to 5V for risk of damaging the non 5V tolerant pin) or that that's a potential problem area depending on Vf?

Comment: it would make more sense to turn on the LED programmatically

Comment: @dualpenguins: Yes.  If the LED supply were much higher than the supply voltage to the microcontroller, the LED would pass current to the pin.  You can usually get away with the LED supply being higher than the micro supply rail by about the minimum forward voltage of the LED.  For example, old-style Green LEDs drop about 2.1 Vdc.  You should be able to run a Green LED from a 5V rail and still have the microcontroller running from the 3.3V rail.

Comment: This is just a side note for next time. Please put reference designators on your components. It makes it much easier to discuss the circuit. Not a big deal just a tip to make things go smoothly for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work but the LED will not be very bright. The proximity sensor you want to use is not intended to sink enough current to light an LED. The typical collector current is only guaranteed to be 0.3 mA when the LED is driven at 20 mA and a white card is placed 0.050 inch from the sensor. That's enough current to pull your 10k resistor low, but it will not give you a very bright LED.

Also, the saturated Vce is 0.4 V at 0.1 mA, so you need an LED with a low forward voltage. Green and blue might not work at all.

I would follow the suggestion from @AndrewMorton and let the RPi give you the visual indication.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice catch - I hadn't considered that. I might have the RPI do it, or add a FET driver. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think this will work- the loading from the LED will prevent the low logic level from being achieved by the phototransistor.

You can add a BSS84 to drive the LED, and that will work fine. Or use another GPIO, which would ensure that the LED is only illuminated when the low logic level is recognized by the MCU.

Comment: Agreed - the datasheet indicates that the opto may only sink 0.3mA when activated, which is adequate for a 10k pull-up but not enough to drive a LED too.  A buffer of some kind would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this depends on the forward voltage (Vf) of the LED, which varies depending on its color. Generally, Vf increases with shorter wavelength. Reds are 1.8 ~ 2.1 so could work, yellow-greens are 2.2 so also ok, true greens, blues and whites are higher than 3V, so not likely. Check your LED’s datasheet.

More here: [How much voltage does a green LED need to be supplied? Will it handle 5V?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297356/how-much-voltage-does-a-green-led-need-to-be-supplied-will-it-handle-5v)

Given your 3.3V supply, there isn’t a lot of margin left to ensure the LED will light if you choose a higher-Vf color. You also have the sensor’s Vce to consider which adds even more overhead.

But the biggest problem will be the sensor's *current transfer ratio*, which will be low - too low for the transistor to really drive an LED.

To overcome this, you could use a P-FET, or an inverting buffer to drive the LED and get the best possible margin to light it. Then you're not loading the transistor.

If you want this LED to be *really* bright, a boost LED driver would do that.

Comment: That's a good point - I suppose since it's a low-side I could drive the LED with 5V and have enough room for all the drops. The LED is really just to have a board-level way to debug and see if the sensors tripped outside of code.

Comment: Yes, if you have 5V available you can do that. Just make sure it doesn’t have a leakage path to get to your GPIO.

Comment: But really, if it’s for debug just use red, yellow or yellow-green.

Answer (score 1):

As the requirement, as clarified in your comment

> I'm assuming you mean the LED is activated - and I care more about the RPI getting the signal.

is that the RPi recognizes the signal, you need the RPi to generate the signal that enables the LED, so the circuit in the question is a wrong solution. You need the RPi to set the LED.

But that doesn't match the part of the question that asks:

> I'd like to add a small LED that turns on when the sensor activates

which would suggest some sort of high-input-impedance buffer between the sensor and an LED driver (perhaps a transistor?).